# Pass user and password from AzureDevops pipeline to springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-devops

I got a pipeline in AzureDevops, that build using mvn java app mit springboot but Spring Security needs a user and password to it so when mvn build and then run app, there is a error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'user-password' in value "${user-password}"

I do not store user and password in *.properties file.
How to do it, to pass secret and password in security way?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of dealing with secrets:

- external management resource like HashiCorp Vault - please take a look on [Spring Vault](https://spring.io/projects/spring-vault)
- putting secrets into variable group and then use [token replace task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens). Make sure that you will do it before creating package for deployment.